# Como usar Boolean em Json

Tags: javascript, json, booleano

Tenho o seguinte JSON, e dentro do meu código tenho uma verificação para saber se o autoLogin está ativado.

```
Object {autoLogin: "true", 
     autoLoginKey: "bWF4LnJvZ2VyaW8=&YWU4NjIwMGJhMTU0NWQzMjQ0ZmRlM2FhYWNiYTJjZmM="}
```

Entretanto para fazer essa verifica uso a valor de `autoLogin`, mas tenho que verificar ele como string.

```
if(key.autoLogin === 'true'){//...code}
```

Como faço para ao invés de comparar como string, comparar como boolean mesmo.

Tipo:

```
if(key.autoLogin === true){//code...}
```

Comment: Pode tentar converter o valor para `boolean` mas é excessivo e perde performance para o que está a tentar fazer. Para no json vir logo como `boolean` tem de ser colocado sem as `"` do lado do server e o `parse` automaticamente mete o tipo certo: `Object {autoLogin: true`

Comment: Sim, mas seto esse valor no localStorage: `localStorage.setItem('autoLogin', true);`, qual é a melhora maneira de se fazer?

Comment: Em localStorage o valor é guardado como `string` por isso o melhor é comparar como `string` mesmo

Comment: hum.... nao sabia deste detalhe... Se quiser responder eu marco como válida.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Partindo do que indicou no comentário, e se está a usar `localStorage` para guardar o valor de `autoLogin` com `true` em `localStorage`, este é guardado como `string`. Para ser mais exato como uma `DOMString`, que é uma `string` em `UTF-16` e que é mapeada diretamente para `string`.

Algo que podemos constatar na [documentação do setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

Isto significa que será guardado como uma `string` e posteriormente também obtido como uma `string` através do `getItem` ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)).

Poderia naturalmente tentar converter o valor que vem do `getItem` para `boolean` para fazer a comparação, utilizando por exemplo o `JSON.parse`:

```
if (JSON.parse(key.autoLogin) === true){
```

Ou até fazer uma função personalizada para converter para `boolean`, embora isso seja pior que fazer a condição que já está neste momento a fazer, como `string`:

```
if (key.autoLogin === 'true'){//...code}
```